# flot charting with jsreport and epoch time on xasis

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, flot, jsreport

I am currently trying to leverage [jsreport](http://jsreport.net) to generate a simple PDF report which contains a graph of bpsIn over a time range.  The data for now is static, but I have run into issues with a few items:

(1)  When I attempt to leverage moment.js to format the data, `moment.unix({{this.[1]}}*1000)` seems to work fine, however, when you add the `.format("YYYY-MM-DD")` on to the end to format the epoch time as human readable, the content disappears from the graph.

I have a playground version setup on jsreport's [playground](https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/ZJGW7Bloyl/1) that illustrates the graph working as a bar chart with the epoch timestamps.  Notice how they're completely unreadable..

Converting it to a line chart is simple.  I've also tried replacing the `mode: "categories"` within the `xasis` of flot to use time, as:

```
xaxis: { 
   mode: "time",
   minTickSize: [15, "minute"],
   min: (new Date(data.points[0][1])).getTime(),
   max: (new Date(data.points[0][29])).getTime(),
   timeformat: "%y/%m/%d"
},
"lines": {"show": "true"},
"points": {"show": "true"},
clickable:true, hoverable: true
```

with the appropriate additional includes:
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js`
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.categories.min.js`
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.min.js`
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.symbol.min.js`

The end goal is to have a report with human readable dates as the xAsis, but the dates are actually 15minute increments as this data is coming from InfluxDB at the moment as some test data.

Comment: Also, from the flot docs, I realize it wants the epoch (UTC) time for the xAsis, which is fine.  I just want to use timeformat to be able to read them.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up answering my own question upon adding the comment to the question about flot wanting the time in UTC (facepalm).